# Transform a Pandas Dataframe Column and Index to Values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, transformation

I have a dataframe in a "yes/no" format like

```
    7   22
1   NaN t
25  t   NaN
```

where "t" stands for yes and I need to transform it to a X-Y table since the column name is the X coordinate and the index is the Y coordinate:

```
  X  Y
1 22  1
2  7 25
```

a pseudo-code like:

```
if a cell = "t":
     newdf.X = df.column(t)
     newdf.Y = df.index(t)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Another option with `stack`:

```
pd.DataFrame.from_records(
    df.stack().index.swaplevel(),
    columns=['X', 'Y'])
```

Output:

```
    X   Y
0  22   1
1   7  25
```

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
# Use np.where to get the integer location of the 't's in the dataframe
r, c = np.where(df == 't')

# Use dataframe constructor with dataframe indexes to define X, Y
df_out = pd.DataFrame({'X':df.columns[c], 'Y':df.index[r]})
df_out
```

Output:

```
    X   Y
0  22   1
1   7  25
```

Update to address [@RajeshC comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66972735/transform-a-pandas-dataframe-column-and-index-to-values#comment118383853_66972948):

Given df,

```
      7   22
1   NaN    t
13  NaN  NaN
25    t  NaN
```

Then:

```
r, c = np.where(df == 't')
df_out = pd.DataFrame({'X':df.columns[c], 'Y':df.index[r]}, index=r)
df_out = df_out.reindex(range(df.shape[0]))
df_out
```

Output:

```
     X     Y
0   22   1.0
1  NaN   NaN
2    7  25.0
```

Comment: In case a row doesn't contain 't', this will remove that row

Comment: @Rajesh... Yes. We need to create a more roboust example.  With an expected output.

Comment: Well to the question that is asked, I think this is an excellent answer..!!

Comment: @anky Thank you for the vote of confidence.

Comment: Thank you for your support. You are a great help! also @RajeshC

Answer (score 0):

Based on the magic of stacking, my answer is a tweak of @Perl's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12399409/kristian-canler) (couldn't comment because reps < 50)-

```
df.stack().to_frame().reset_index().drop(0,axis = 1).rename(columns = {'level_0':"Y","level_1":"X"}).reindex(columns=["X","Y"])
```

*PS - Thanks [Kristian Canler](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12399409/kristian-canler) for the edit.*

Comment: I think this might be ok as a separate answer, but please remove the images and paste in output and format it as you would format code. Thanks!